# xml error xsl stylesheet

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have the following errors

error on line 1 at column 40: Extra content at the end of the document

When try to output xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="producers.xsl"?>
<producers>
  <producer>
    <id>8</id>
    <name>Emåmejeriet</name>
    <street>Grenvägen 1-3</street>
    <postal>577 39</postal>
    <city>Hultsfred</city>
    <weburl>http://www.emamejerie3t.se</weburl>
  </producer>
</producers>
```

I have validated the xml and I get no errors.
the xsl template looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <head><title>Producenter</title></head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="producers/producer/id"/>
        </p>
    </body>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Works for me, are files really using utf-8 encoding?

Comment: Have you tried the existing answer? Your current xslt produces output that is not well formed as it has more than one root element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Html tag missing.
XML must have a one root element, (you have two - **head** and **body**)
Error persists after string

```
<head><title>Producenter</title></head>
```

when the validator find a second root element (**body**).

just add root **html** tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>

    <head><title>Producenter</title></head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="producers/producer/id"/>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: ahiipsa, `html` may be omitted and is not the cause of the error. What causes the reported error is the fact that an XML declatation is output and this makes some browser expect a (well-formed) XML document to be produced by the transformation. Setting `<xsl:output method="html"/>` fixes this problem and the browsers no longer produce an error message. This should be understood well: I am not saying that `html` element must not be present -- just that its presence isn't necessary in order to fix the problem.

Comment: I agree with you completely. This problem has two solutions, add the root element or change output method.
ps. Sorry for my English. I use google translate :)

Comment: i start a bounty accidentally, just try it :)

Comment: @ahipsa, Don't regret the accident -- the bounty helped attract interest and now we have a corect and precise solution. +1 from me, to contribute for recovering your 100 points :)

Comment: thanks, this is the right experience for me, I'm just learning)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the error messages from Safari and Opera (IE and Firefox process the XML file OK, Chrome hangs up):

**Safari**:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 40: Extra content at the end of the document
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
>
> This document was created as the result of an XSL transformation. The
>   line and column numbers given are from the transformed result.

**Opera**:

> This document had an invalid XSLT stylesheet. Error message from the
>   XSLT engine: Error: invalid XML output: unexpected start-tag (root
>   element already specified)

The message from Safari is especially good -- it confirms that the issue is not in performing the transformation, but it is with the generated result.

The message from Opera isn't so good, but both browsers talk about the same thing: they treat the result of the transformation not as HTML, but as XML and report the fact that the result isn't a well-formed XML document (not a single top element).

**Indeed, the transformation generates this output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><head><title>Producenter</title></head><body><p>8</p></body>
```

and the XML declaration makes the browsers expect an XML document, only to find that this isn't a well-formed XML document.

**Solution**:

Based on the analysis, the fix is easy and natural -- just add this:

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

immediately after the `xsl:stylesheet` instruction.

**The complete transformation now becomes**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <head><title>Producenter</title></head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="producers/producer/id"/>
        </p>
    </body>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The output generated no longer starts with an XML declaration and the content type is clearly specified as `text/html`:**

```
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

   <title>Producenter</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p>8</p>
</body>
```

**and both Safari and Opera happily display the result with no error messages.**

**Remember**: When producing HTML output, always specify this explicitly in an `<xsl:output>` instruction.

**Do Note**: While this answer reveals the true cause to the problem and provides a solution, this doesn't exclude the need to write good and complete HTML documents. Thus, it *is* good to specify `html` as the top element of the document. An added benefit is that if the top element of the generated output is `html`, an XSLT processor automatically deducts that the output must be "html" and performs html serialization even without having explicit specification of the output method.

**According to the [W3C XSLT 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output)**:

> The default for the method attribute is chosen as follows. If
>
> - the root node of the result tree has an element child,
> - the expanded-name of the first element child of the root node (i.e.    the document element) of the result tree has local part html (in any
>     combination of upper and lower case) and a null namespace URI, and
> - any text nodes preceding the first element child of the root node of the result tree contain only whitespace characters,
>
> then the default output method is html; otherwise, the default output
>   method is xml.